# Multiple "Value" queries in TFS 12.0

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to include multiple values in a TFS query so that I don't have to create separate AND clauses?

Right now I'm having to do the following.

```
AND > STATE <> CLOSED
AND > STATE <> RESOLVED
AND > STATE <> COMPLETED
```

I'm just trying to find all tasks that are NOT closed, completed, or resolved. What I have above currently works, but I'm just wondering if I can do this with ONE clause (I was thinking I could separate these by commas (like closed, completed, resolved), but that's not working - when I use commas, it actually seems to ignore everything and show every item).

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use **In** to search for any value in a delimited set. Separate values with the list separator that corresponds to the regional settings that are defined for your client computer. For example, you might use a comma(,). More details [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/query-operators-variables#operators):

```
State   IN    New, Active
```

[image: New Query Windows with States]

But there is no NOT IN equivalent. [This has been added since this answer was written.]

You don't need to group the states though (it's one less step)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But actually now that I look at it, (personally) it makes the query easier to look at and manage with separate AND clauses. Thank you again.

Comment: @DaveShaw I didn't know you could do that, thanks. The clunky way I always used to do this was: "And state = New" grouped with "Or state=Active"

Comment: Care to post a screen of how you did. I'm trying this very thing and it renders different results, so I'm guessing it's the syntax issue. Do I need any delimiters or braces in the list that I'm related the *in* to? When I go *State=Active or State=New* I get results. When I change it to *State in Active,New* I get nada... [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286638.aspx) says that *he list separator that corresponds to the regional settings* but I've tried comma, semicolon and a bunch of other stuff...

Comment: @KonradViltersten I've added an image

Comment: That's **precisely** how I set up my *State* line. Either you went PhotoShop on it or my TFS doesn't like me... I gave you +1 anyway for attentiveness. Any ideas why mine is misbehaving?

Comment: No, and no idea, that worked fine for me in TFS 2012.4.

Comment: Multiple values also don't work for "Does not contain". A value like "Closed,Resolved" doesn't work, it must be separate filters with "Closed" AND "Resolved".

Comment: You probably know by now @RobG,  but [Contains and Does Not Contain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-operators-variables?view=vsts#query-operators) only applies to `String`s.

Comment: In later TFS versions, there is also a corresponding 'Not In' operator.